# Determine source of API request?

Tags: javascript

I have been introduced to a web application that I need to make some modifications to.

The app is huge, and there are perhaps 100 Javascript files. These files send requests to a third party API all the time.

Now, in the console, I can see all these requests. Let's say that one looks like:

```
GET http://123.456.789.10:8000/v1/accounts/accountnum/children?_=1422026843600
```

Then of course I can see the parameters sent, headers and response. My problem is that I need to locate the JS file which is sending one particular request. Searching all the files for the API target URL reveals that 40 or 50 files  send requests to this same URL, with similar parameters.

Is there a way I can find out the source file of one specific request? Something like `sent from filename.js on line 123` would be ideal, but just the file name would be of great help too.

I could go through all the files and try each one individually, but that seems like a huge waste of time. There would be A LOT of code to go through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what to do in the application to make the request occur, in Chrome you can use an XHR breakpoint to catch it:

1. Navigate to the point where you're about to do the thing that causes the request
2. Open Dev Tools
3. Switch to the Sources tab
4. On the right, scroll down to "XHR Breakpoints"
5. Click the `+` button, fill in some appropriate subset of the URL (or leave it blank to break on all XHR)
6. Add it
7. Do the thing that does the request

Chrome will break and take you to the line of code that was triggering the XHR.

Comment: Also if you go to "Network" tab, when the request is done then it will be shown, the column "Initiator" has the file and line

Comment: I've tried the sources/XHR solution, when I type in a portion of the URL and press Enter then Chrome indeed breaks, but it displays line 1 of the jQuery1.6.2.js file which is obviously wrong as the request could not be coming from the jQuery include...trying the Network tab now, same thing! I don't understand, any ideas?

Comment: For some other requests, the "initiator" field just says "Other" instead of file name and line.

Comment: @jovan: It's not at all surprising that the XHR request is coming from jQuery; the code in question is probably using jQuery's `ajax` function (or one of its wrappers). Just look at the call stack to find what's calling jQuery to do that, and in recent versions of Chrome you can "black box" the jQuery script file. I haven't tried XHR breakpoints with a black-boxed script, but in general what black boxing does is skip over that script so you stay within your own source.